# mssql как правильно получить уникальные значения по дате

Tags: sql, sql-server, typeorm

У меня есть две таблицы, одна с типами игр, а вторая с тиражами.
Первая GameType c колонками: GameTypeID, GameName, IsActive.
Вторая Draw: DrawID, GameTypeID, DrawNo, DrawDate.

Как правильно составить запрос, чтобы соеденить эти две таблицы и получить только IsActive=1, DrawNo, DrawDate - только одна следующая игра по каждому GameType

Comment: Покажите CREATE TABLE, а не словесно описывайте структуру. Приведите пример данных (INSERT INTO) и требуемый ответ для этих данных. С пояснениями, почему именно так.

Answer (score 0):

Пока получилось только так

```
SELECT * FROM GameType
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Draw.GameTypeID AS GameID, MIN(Draw.DrawDate) AS DrawDate
FROM Draw
WHERE Draw.DrawDate >= GETDATE()
GROUP BY Draw.GameTypeID) AS New ON New.GameID=GameType.GameTypeID
```